# Objective-C block parameter Issue: This block declaration is not a prototype

Tags: ios, objective-c, block

I am learning [ReactiveObjC](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveObjC) , the ReactiveCocoa Objective-C version.

For the code following:  In `RACSignal.h` ,

```
- (RACSignal *)reduceEach:(id _Nullable (^)())reduceBlock RAC_WARN_UNUSED_RESULT;
```

> (id _Nullable (^)**()**)

Xcode reports a error:

> This block declaration is not a prototype

Multiple parameters could be put in the `reduceBlock()`. 
As the code following:  In `UIAlertView+RACSignalSupport.m` , and others ,

```
- (RACSignal *)rac_buttonClickedSignal {
    RACSignal *signal = [[[[self.rac_delegateProxy
        signalForSelector:@selector(alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:)]
        reduceEach:^(UIAlertView *alertView, NSNumber *buttonIndex){
            return buttonIndex;
        }]
    ......
    return signal;
}
```

Kinda generic. I think I can put zero or more parameters in the block, with `void (^block)()` declared.

The syntax is not supported now in Xcode.
I want to know how to solve it, and why.

Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can get the "not a prototype" warning when you try to define a function or block prototype using an empty set of parentheses `()`.

Put a `void` in the middle of the parens—i.e. `(id _Nullable (^)(void))`, and you should fix the problem.

Comment: I think , the answer is that way ` (id _Nullable (^)(id _Nullable ,...))`, It's  not that easy . *(id _Nullable (^)())*, I saw the syntax many times.

Comment: @dengApro Did you try it? The default warning settings for Clang in Xcode have gotten stricter about this in recent versions. Putting `void` in the parens really should fix it.

Comment: I tried. **reduceEach:(id _Nullable (^)(void))reduceBlock** , And it kills the func  **reduceEach:^(UIAlertView *alertView, NSNumber *buttonIndex){**

Comment: Putting `void` is recommended by clang. i want to know better solutions. Like `NSString stringWithFormat`, the parameter is zero or more

Comment: @dengApro Then just define it as variadic, the way `-[NSString stringWithFormat:]` does, using an ellipsis. `(id _Nullable (^)(NSString *, ...))`

Comment: @dengApro: To add to CharlesSrstka's comment, if you use block type with a variadic parameter, then the block implementation needs to actually take a variadic. The type must match the block signature. If you try to call a block expression with a block type that doesn't match the actual signature of the block that it points to at runtime, it will cause undefined behavior.

Comment: @newacct， I think you can post a answer , and show me some code.

Comment: @dengApro Here's a [short example of a variadic function in C](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Variadic-Example.html).

Comment: Thanks, @Charles Srstka. I did not figure it out today . *ReactiveObjC*'s Objective-C syntax is complicated . i will try tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

If you redefine your signature to accept an array instead of an arbitrary number of parameters, then you’ll workaround it easily